# Оповещения в определённое время Java

Tags: java

Всем добрый день, хочу сделать так, чтобы действие происходило в определённый момент времени, допустим каждый год 01.01 числа звучала какая-нибудь мелодия. Как так сделать, ведь нельзя же просто загнать всё это дело в отдельный поток с бесконечным циклом, ведь вдруг у меня будет выполнятся по 10 таких проверок одновременно, то это вызовет ужасную нагрузку на процессор. Буду рад, если покажете как это делается, может что-то поновее и получше появилось?)

Comment: Можно посмотреть в сторону [enRoute](http://enroute.osgi.org/services/osgi.enroute.scheduler.api.html) - `Cron Schedules`

Comment: @AndreyM а как мне это скачать?

Comment: [GitHub enRoute](https://github.com/osgi/osgi.enroute/tree/master/osgi.enroute.base.api) - набор интерфейсов, там же [реализацию](https://github.com/osgi/osgi.enroute/tree/master/osgi.enroute.scheduler.simple.provider/src/osgi/enroute/scheduler/simple/provider) можно надыбать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите запускать некоторые события с определенным периодом, то лучше воспользоваться `ScheduledExecutorService` как предложил `Nofate`. Но если вам необходимо исполнять код в строго определенный день или скажем в строго определенное время, то лучше взять [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).

В нем вы сможете создать `job`'ы и задать парядок выполнения:

```
 trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
    .withSchedule(dailyAtHourAndMinute(10, 42))
    .forJob(myJobKey)
    .build();
```

Данный пример означает, что мы будем запускать нашу задачу ежедневно в 10:42.

Или можно задать более конкретно:

```
  trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0/2 8-17 * * ?"))
    .forJob("myJob", "group1")
    .build();
```

Это означает, что наша задача будет исполняться каждые две минуты ежедневно с 8 утра до 5 вечера.

Преимущество данного подхода в том, что мы не зависим от времени старта и перезапуска приложения. Оно у нас строго фиксировано.

Comment: Просто замечательно!

Answer (score 0):

Есть очень классный framework, называется [apache camel framework](https://camel.apache.org).
Суть camel в том, что вы можете быстро и удобно запрограммировать некий маршрут с некоей последовательностью действий.
Camel поддерживает кучу компонент и протоколов. Очень много готовых решений.

В вашем случае, требуется, например, компонента [apache camel timer](https://camel.apache.org/timer.html), которая запускается с заданной периодичностью и активирует маршрут с заданной последовательностью действий.

То есть будет примерно такой код:

```
from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=60s")
.bean(MyMelodyRunner);
```

Где каждые 60 секунд будет запускаться ваш некий класс `MyMelodyRunner` и запускать `bean`-метод, в котором вы и напишите свой код, играющий мелодию и/или рассылающий письма :).

Comment: Не совсем, по сути это то же самое, что и Timer Swing'a, мне бы пришлось не выключать целый год программу и комп, чтобы это сработало. Мне скорее нужно это всё дело сделать не через промежуток времени, а через именно дату и время, когда проигрываться мелодия.

Comment: @ProstoCoder, значит Ваш вопрос неправильно сформулирован. Так и напишите - "как запустить приложение Java на выключенном компьютере?".

Comment: @MikhailGrebenev *"как запустить приложение Java на выключенном компьютере?"* Вопрос же не про это.

Answer (score 0):

Из коробки в Java есть класс [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), позволяющий запустить задачу через определенное время или с заданной периодичностью.

```
ScheduledExecutorService pool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
// 1 - количество потоков, которые одновременно исполняют задачи
```

Вы создаете экземпляр задачи:

```
Runnable task = () -> {
    // ваша задача
};
```

вычисляете отсрочку для задачи от текущего момента, например в миллисекундах, и закидываете задачу в планировщик:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 1);
long delay = LocalDate.now().until(date, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
pool.schedule(task, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

При этом вы не гоняете процессор вхолостую и все красиво.

Если вы хотите, чтобы запланированные задачи переживали перезапуск вашей программы, нужно будет дополнительно повозиться: хранить список задач во внешнем файле или базе данных, подгружать на старте, вычеркивать выполненные.

Если цель - не повозиться с кодом, а решить задачу, можно посмотреть  готовые решения: [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), [db-scheduler](https://github.com/kagkarlsson/db-scheduler)

Comment: Спасибо, Quartz отлично подошёл!