# Spring Boot уведомление по времени

Tags: java, spring-boot

Приложение состоит из нескольких полей, основные "message", "time", "email".
 Цель сделать подобие будильника. 
 На данном этапе я пишу сообщение, время и email куда отправить, и у меня  сразу улетает письмо с сообщением, при этом запись сохраняется.  Подскажите, как обработать событие после сохранения, для того чтобы письмо улетало в соответствии с указанным временем. Может какая аннотация или метод. P.S. я нубас )

```
@Controller
public class NotificationController {
    @Autowired
    private CommandRepository commandRepository;

    @Autowired
    private NotificationService notificationService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String command(Map<String,Object> model)
    {
        Iterable<Command> commands = commandRepository.findAll();

        model.put("commands", commands);
        return "command";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String add(@RequestParam String name,
                      @RequestParam String message,
                      @RequestParam String time,
                      @RequestParam String email,
                      Map<String, Object> model)
    {
        Command command = new Command(name, message, time, email);

        commandRepository.save(command);

        notificationService.sendNotification(command);

        Iterable<Command> commands = commandRepository.findAll();

        model.put("commands", commands);

        return "command";
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Периодичные запросы к внешнему серверу средствами Spring](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/801338/204271)

Comment: обновление метода по средствам крона я знаю, вопрос в том как или где организовать метод, чтобы письмо улетало согласно, указанному времени.

Comment: Предполагаю, что нужно взять значение отправленного времени из репозитория и сравнить его с текущим, если совпадает, то отослать сообщение

Comment: @JanJack приведите пример как у вас выглядит String time

Comment: И как часто должен работать будильник? Раз в час, минуту, день, месяц?

Comment: 1 раз должен сработать, отослать письмо, в указанное время, хотя можно и повторы поставить

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь, что решение не очень простое. Подробнее можете почитать вот тут: [Оповещения в определённое время Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/720419/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-java).

Если вы используете Spring и решили не использовать Quartz, то рекомендую в качестве пула использовать ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor(){
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5); //TODO configurable properties
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10); //TODO configurable properties
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
```

}

И затем подцепить этот бин в компоненте.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос, просто добавив метод

```
@Scheduled(cron = CRON)
    public void notifyMail()
    {
        long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String curStringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(l);

        if(timeList != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < timeList.size(); i++) {
                if (curStringDate.equals(timeList.get(i))) {
                    javaMailSender.send(mailMessage);
                    timeList.remove(i);
                    System.out.println("done");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```